# Verify that a user is at/near a certain location (no GPS)

Tags: rest, gps, location, authorization, verification

We're building an application based on a RESTful architecture.
So, when being at a certain position, users are shown a link, which allows them to visit an invite-only web site.

How can I make sure that only people at/near this location have access to the web site? Theoretically anyone with the link could access the site (e.g. if the link is shared by someone being there)? Is this even possible with a RESTful architecture?